# What to do when an error occurs in Boost Test fixture?

Tags: c++, testing, boost, fixtures, boost-test

I want to be able to prematurely exit a test suite (in Boost Test) from within the fixture constructor due to the possibility of errors in the initialization code (non-existent input file in particular). Should I just call exit() or is there a cleaner alternative?

Comment: Could you plant a check such as `BOOST_REQUIRE_NO_THROW` inside the fixture's constructor body?

Comment: I could `BOOST_REQUIRE(false)` if I wanted a forced failure. I wanted to know if the framework had a built-in for my situation. Apparently not.